# JavaScript promises .then and setTimeout ordering

Tags: javascript, promise

```html
getAllUsers(): void {
    this.allUsers = this.userService.getUsers()
      .then(res => this.allUsers = res)
      .then(() => setTimeout( () =>
      this.allUsers.forEach( user => console.log(user)), 2000
      ))
      .then(() => setTimeout(this.restOfInit(), 4000))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error)));
    // console.log(this.allUsers[0]);
    // setTimeout(() =>     console.log(this.allUsers[0]), 3000);
}
```

In the attached snippet, I would expect the logging of all the users to happen before the `restOfInit` function, since there's a difference of 2 seconds between the timeouts. However, what actually happens is that `restOfInit` is run first, logging a string to console, and all the users are logged to console after that. Why is this happening?

Comment: `this.restOfInit(), 4000` Delete the parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1) The functions passed to `setTimeout()` execute asynchronously in approximately the number of milliseconds specified. You're likely aware of this. However, the calls to `setTimeout()` return (almost immediately) without regard to the time specified.

2) You want to pass `this.restOfInit` instead of `this.restOfInit()`. The former passes the function to `setTimeout()`. The latter invokes the function with no arguments and passes the return value (possibly `undefined`) to setTimeout().

**tldr;**

```
.then(() => setTimeout(this.restOfInit(), 4000)) // Change this line

.then(() => setTimeout(this.restOfInit, 4000))  // to this
```

Comment: Right, I was aware of 1), but 2) explains the problem, obviously the function should be sent and not invoked immediately. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

As correctly stated by @fvgs, the problem with the firing order you are seeing lies with the immediate invocation of `this.restOfInit` - its return value being passed to `setTimeout` instead of the function itself.

However using timeouts here defeats the point of promises. Promises should allow you to schedule the order precisely, and will execute as quickly as they can, rather than a guaranteed waiting period no matter how fast your request for users takes. Yours actually does not need to be chained at all as only the first callback needs the resolution values. It would be far easier to schedule like this...

```
    getAllUsers(): void {
      this.userService.getUsers()
        .then(res => {
          this.allUsers = res
          this.allUsers.forEach(user => console.log(user))
          this.restOfInit()
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error)));
    }
```

Also side note - the assigning of the `this.allUsers = this.userService.getUsers()` chain will be a promise, but then in the callback you assign `this.allUsers = res` which by the looks of it will be an array. I suspect this may be the reason you have used `setTimeout` as it could be overwriting it when you don't expect it.

Unless you need to further interact with the promise chain there is no need for `this.allUsers = this.userService.getUsers()` so i have omitted this in the code above

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks, that's very helpful.